# sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: connection was closed in the middle of operation

Tags: python, asynchronous, session, sqlalchemy

I have a telegram bot, it worked on the server (where DBMS PostgreSQL also is hosted) and on server there wasn't any problem
Now I want to change something, and started bot on my Windows 10 home machine -- and DBMS is still on server. And when bot does nothing for about 10 minutes (system doesn't go to sleep mode, I swithed sleep mode activation off) - bot raises this error on incoming message handling:

sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.Error) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.ConnectionDoesNotExistError'>: connection was closed in the middle
of operation

Here is an example of service method -- everyone of them is similar (starts with "async with async_session() as session:" and ends with "await session.commit()" if smth changes)

```
conn_str = "postgresql+asyncpg://[user]:[password]@[ip]:5433/[dbname]" # on server [ip] replaced by "0.0.0.0"

async_engine = create_async_engine(
   conn_str,
   future=True
)

async_session = sessionmaker(bind=async_engine, class_=AsyncSession,
                             expire_on_commit=False)


async def some_method([args]):
    async with async_session() as session:
        statement = ...
        users = await session.exec(statement)
        user = users.first()

        [change smth on user]

        await session.commit()
```

Don't know what to do in this situation..
Was it just a luck that on server this exception didn't occure, or it's just windows problems with keeping session alive?

Comment: found topic with suggestion to add pool_pre_ping=True and it seems to work, but maybe there is better solution so won't delete this topic..